# How do you make a music block play a sound in Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Pocket Edition just randomly stopped playing music for my music block. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, I also tried to check the settings but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing [Jukebox](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Jukebox) with [Note block](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Note_Block)? They look very similar, but act differently

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think what you meant to say is note block, if so how you make sounds is to place it on a specific block. Each block well have it's own sound.

Hope this helped!!

Answer (score -1):

I've searched the web and found [this post](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1964185-no-sound-on-minecraft-pe-for-ipad#c7) on the Minecraft forum. It suggests restarting your device, or plugging in and unplugging headphones.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a similar problem before, and restarting the game and/or your device could help. Also double check that there is no block above the note block